# sed command to add 2 spaces to each line input from output

Tags: shell, sed, android, posix

In a sed command I need to essentially add 2+ space to each line copied from the output to the input and then delete the last line from the output when input.  This is what I have:

```
sed -i -e '/PLACEHOLDER/ r TestOutput.txt' -e s/PLACEHOLDER// SQLInput.txt
```

The sed command already imports from the output to the input and deletes PLACEHOLDER, but I can't figure out how to get it to add 2 spaces to each line that was input from the output.  Keep in mind, the input would also contain other variables and functions that I don't want to change.

Output:

```
WORD
WORD
WORD
WORD
```

Input:

```
PLACEHOLDER
```

Expected input after sed command:

```
  WORD
  WORD
  WORD
  WORD
```

Comment: Maybe prepare a copy of test output that already has the spaces?

Comment: The usage of "input" and "output" in this question is *really* confusing.

Comment: `sed` doesn't process files read with the `r` command, so the only way to do this with a single `sed` command would be to give both files as arguments; the first will placed to the hold space with added whitespaces, than in the second the placeholder gets replaced by the pattern space. This is easy if there is some method to identify the end of the `TestOutput.txt` or the beginning of the input file. So we need more information of the actual file contents.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on exactly where you want to add space but I guess that may help you:

```
sed -i -e '/PLACEHOLDER/ r TestOutput.txt' -e 's/PLACEHOLDER//;s/^/  /' SQLInput.txt
```

the `^` is a start line anchor, so the statement `s/^/  /` is basically just adding two space at the beginning of any lines.

Comment: Wrong. The file read with `r` command is directed to the output without going through the pattern space, so it will not get processed.